# Stripe/subscription payments on Expo managed workflows

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, expo

I'm building a cross-platform app in React Native that needs to support a paid tier subscription in order to access some premium content. I'm using Expo managed workflow and I've been looking at Stripe as a possible solution which I believe comes pre-installed on managed workflows.

Does anyone have experience implementing similar functionality that could offer advice? I've read that projects may need to be ejected from expo which I would prefer not to do!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with the expo and wanted to use expo payment API then you have to `eject the expo` and need to migrate on `expo-kit` which offers to access the expo payment API for stripe, But if you don't want to eject then you have to build the UI for getting details like `card number`, `expiry`, `CVC` and then other details and follow this to hit API's.

https://medium.com/@rafael.rpadovani/stripe-payments-with-sca-in-react-native-15a4926e14f